# Problem related to functional equation and definite integrals

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

I have  replaced x with 1/x and I added both equations...but it didn't help me. Can anyone help me with this problem..I am not sure about which formula to apply in this question[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$3f(x)+4f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x}-10$$
$$x' \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$$
$$3f(x')+4f(\frac{1}{x'})=\frac{1}{x'}-10$$
$$3f(\frac{1}{x})+4f(x)=x-10$$
Solving for f(x):
$$3*(3f(x)+4f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x}-10)-4*(3f(\frac{1}{x})+4f(x)=x-10)$$
$$-7f(x)=\frac{3}{x}-4x+10$$
$$f(x)=-\frac{3}{7x}+\frac{4x}{7}-\frac{10}{7}$$
And then you can integrate.
$$\int_2^3 -\frac{3}{7x}+\frac{4x}{7}-\frac{10}{7} dx $$
$$= (-\frac{3}{7}ln(x)+\frac{2x^2}{7}-\frac{10x}{7})|_2^3$$
$$= -\frac{3}{7}ln(\frac{2}{3})$$